# How can I solve an iPhone 4S restore failure loop?

Tags: itunes, iphone, restore

My iPhone crashed while it was connected to the computer. I performed synchronization and left the phone so it can recharge. When I looked it after some time I saw Apple logo. I have tried multiple times to reset it (power + home) but every time it just stuck on Apple logo.

After some time I gave up and decided to restore it but even that didn't work. Each time it just stuck on the progress bar. Here are things I have tried:

- different USB ports
- different sync. cables
- different machines (desktop and laptop)
- windows and mac
- DFU mode

every time same result.

Bringing iPhone to the Apple store is not an option because I am in a unsupported country without the Apple stores.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you did the DFU correctly? Had you jailbroken the phone before this point?

Comment: As I know DFU mode is when the screen is black and iTunes recognize it and offers restore. Yes, it was jailbroken but this didn't meter before.

Comment: Sometimes depending on how an iPhone is jailbroken or if the jailbreak has a problem, it can result in corrupted firmware, which in some cases can be unrecoverable.

Comment: @hellothere Any reference on that? I don't agree with that.

Comment: It's not common but I have seen it happen. Might be due to a faulty phone of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try [RecBoot](http://sebby.net/recboot-mac/recboot_2_2.zip) from [sebby.net](http://www.sebby.net/) for Mac ([and Windows](http://www.mediafire.com/?xhlteg976vla8mz)).

The RecBoot application lets you put your iPhone into and out of recovery mode easily.